# Using the same object for ObjectType and InputObjectType

Tags: scala, graphql, sangria

I have a model object defined like this:

```
case class OrganizationId(value: Long) extends AnyVal with TypedId

case class OrganizationFields(name: String, iban: Option[String], bic: Option[String])

case class Organization(
  id: OrganizationId, addressId: AddressId, updatedAt: LocalDateTime, insertedAt: LocalDateTime, fields: OrganizationFields
)
```

And here is what I'm trying to do in my sangria schema definition:

```
implicit val OrganizationFields = deriveObjectType[GraphqlContext, OrganizationFields]()
  implicit val OrganizationType: ObjectType[GraphqlContext, Organization] = deriveObjectType[GraphqlContext, Organization]()
implicit val OrganizationInputType = deriveInputObjectType[OrganizationFields]()
```

I need to define `OrganizationFields` both as an `ObjectType` to be able to use `Organization` in my graphql queries and also as an `ObjectInputType` to be able to use it in my graphql mutation as input.
The issue is that I get the following exception at run time:
`Type name 'OrganizationFields' is used for several conflicting GraphQL type kinds: ObjectType, InputObjectType. Conflict found in an argument 'organization' defined in field 'createOrganization' of 'Mutation' type`
Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, both GraphQL types would have the same name. This is not allowed since all types within a GraphQL schema share the same global namespace.

You can rename one of these types in order to solve this issue. For example:

```
implicit val OrganizationInputType = deriveInputObjectType[OrganizationFields](
  InputObjectTypeName("OrganizationFieldsInput"))
```